# Error: Side-by-Side configuration info for file.OCX contains errors. Application has failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, delphi, ocx, dllregistration

I get the following error when trying to register an ocx on a particular machine. (windows xp 32 bit)

Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "file.OCX" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).

But it works fine on my Windows7 32 bit and another Windows7 64 bit machine.

The only difference I can see besides the operating system is that on the two machines it works we have 
Delphi 2009 and Microsoft visual studio installed.  (From what I read Visual studio may have something to do with it.)

How could I go about getting this ocx to register properly on a Machine without Microsoft visual studio?

Thanks

P.S.

The manifest version is 1.0 (in the ocx file) if that helps.

Here is the manifest

```
 <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
- <dependency>
- <dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" /> 
 </dependentAssembly>
 </dependency>
- <dependency>
- <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50608.0"             processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" /> 
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
 - <dependency>
- <dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.MFC" version="8.0.50608.0"    processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b" /> 
   </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
   </assembly>
```

Comment: What's in the manifest. Take a look at it with a resource viewer. Could be that it specifies a dependency on MSVCRT. If that is not installed then you'd see the error that you report. Installing the appropriate redist package for MSVCRT will fix it. The OCX vendor should be specifying such pre-requisites.

Comment: I'm not even sure if I am doing it right but I downloaded a manifest viewer..  By default it was only letting me open dll files..  So I opened a couple of the dll's associated with the ocx's.

Comment: Never mind I just told it to look for all files.  Here is what I got - now adding it to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest indicates that the component has dependencies on MSVCRT and MFC, version 8, aka VS2008. You will need to install those dependencies on any machine that needs this OCX. This means installing the re-distributable packages that MS supply.

I would expect that the OCX vendor details these dependencies and recommend consulting the OCX documentation.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638 - This happened to be what i needed to install for version="8.0.50727.762" and it works great.  Thanks